# Fill an array to a maximum amount (memcpy vs vector)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, stdvector, memcpy

My class dynamically allocates an array of integers (in the code below named `this_data`), but the array can only be filled up to a maximum length (`this_data_maxlen`). I would like to add data (`add_data`) to the array, but the adding array could exceed the maximum length.

Knowing that there is no reallocate for `new` keywords, I wrote one version that uses `memcpy` and another version that uses `vector`, as that was suggested to be the most efficient way. However when testing, the `vector` version turns out the be 5 times slower than the `memcpy`. Am I doing something wrong in the `vector` version?

Memcpy version:

```
unsigned int this_data_len=50;
unsigned int this_data_maxlen=70;           //maximum length of existing dataset
unsigned int add_data_len=50;

int *this_data = new int[this_data_len];    //existing dataset
int *add_data = new int[add_data_len];      //data we want to add to existing dataset

//function here that puts values in them

unsigned int new_data_len=min(this_data_maxlen,this_data_len+add_data_len);     //calculate the new dataset length (=7)
int *new_data=new int[new_data_len];        //create the new dataset

//build the new 'this_data'
memcpy(new_data,this_data,this_data_len*sizeof(int));   //copy existing dataset values to new dataset
memcpy(new_data+this_data_len,add_data,(this_data_maxlen-this_data_len)*sizeof(int));       //fill up the new dataset with a selection of the data to add
delete [] this_data;                        //remove original dataset
this_data=new_data;                         //set the new dataset

//build the new 'add_data'
add_data_len=add_data_len-(this_data_maxlen-this_data_len); //update the add_data length (=2)
new_data=new int[add_data_len];
memcpy(new_data,add_data+(this_data_maxlen-this_data_len),add_data_len*sizeof(int));
delete [] add_data;
add_data=new_data;

this_data_len=new_data_len;                 //set the new dataset length

//clean up
delete [] this_data;
delete [] add_data;
```

Vector version:

```
unsigned int this_data_len=50;
unsigned int this_data_maxlen=70;           //maximum length of existing dataset
unsigned int add_data_len=50;

vector<int> this_vector(this_data_len);
vector<int> add_vector(add_data_len);

//function here that puts values in them

unsigned int new_data_len=min(this_data_maxlen,this_data_len+add_data_len);     //calculate the new dataset length (=7)
this_vector.reserve(new_data_len);
this_vector.insert(this_vector.end(),add_vector.begin(),add_vector.begin()+(this_data_maxlen-this_data_len));
add_vector=vector<int>(add_vector.begin()+(this_data_maxlen-this_data_len),add_vector.end());

add_data_len=add_data_len-(this_data_maxlen-this_data_len); //update the add_data length (=2)
this_data_len=new_data_len;                 //set the new dataset length
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: There is no `new` operator that is analogous to `realloc`. Check out this SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557866/reallocating-memory-via-new-in-c

Comment: You're using the wrong form of delete (`delete this_data` instead of `delete [] this_data`).  I suggest you use `std::vector` -- the `vector` class is designed to do what you're doing in the most optimal way possible (if we assume the compiler library authors are top-notch programmers, which they usually are).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - thanks for noting the `delete` issue. The initial reason I'm not using vector is because the data is loaded and stored as a single block from a binary file - until just now I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2780397/2710064) that allows vectors anyway.

Comment: Part (2) is certainly "Yes - use a vector". For part (1): The vector (with standard allocator) cannot do a `realloc`-like operation, it still will `new` a new block and copy or move the contents when the vector grows beyond capacity. To get realloc-like behaviour you will have to implement your own container that uses `realloc`. AFAIK it's not possible to write a standard allocator that can realloc without moving.

Comment: 1) Use `vector::erase` instead of `add_vector=vector<int>` 2) Did you checked time in release or in debug mode ?

Comment: When some people say that `vector` is hugely slower than their hand rolled pointer stuff, chances are that either they have unnecessarily copied the vector multiple times, or that they don't turn on optimization.

Comment: Thanks @borisbn - and I indeed forgot that debug version is slower. Runs at similar speeds now in release.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests do not seem equivalent. In particular, this line may be doing a lot more work than you intended:

```
add_vector = vector<int>(add_vector.begin() + (this_data_maxlen - this_data_len),
                         add_vector.end());
```

At the very minimum, this line is likely to be creating a temporary vector, deleting the contents of the original vector, and possibly doing a copy of the temporary vector's contents into the original vector before deleting it. (With RVO, or with the move semantics of C++11, some of that may be avoided.)

And all this is to implement the effect of

```
add_vector.erase(add_vector.begin(),
                 add_vector.begin() + (this_data_maxlen - this_data_len));
```

As another comment, if you're always adding data to the end and removing it form the beginning, you may be better off using a `std::queue` or `std::deque` instead of a `std::vector`.

(After I wrote this up, I saw that borisbn and C.R. have already provided the information on using vector::erase hours before me. Hats off to you both.)